# Compute the rotation degrees from transformation matrix in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, 3d

Assume I have 3 original points in a 3D object (in 3D space) as `A1=<xa,ya,za>`, `A2=<xa,ya,za>`, and `A3=<xa,ya,za>`. The 3D object is moved and rotated in the 3D space, and the destination points in that object become `B1=<xb,yb,zb>`, `B2=<xb,yb,zb>`, and `B3=<xb,yb,zb>`.

How can I compute the transformation matrix and following that, the degree of rotation in each axis? Basically, I need a matrix that if applied to all points, I get the displaced object.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: You might find [this paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/papers/Absolute_Orientation.pdf) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call the transformation matrix $\mathbf{M}$,
$$\mathbf{M} = \left [ \begin{matrix} m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13} \\
m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23} \\
m_{32} & m_{32} & m_{33} \end{matrix} \right ]$$
your three original vectors
$$\begin{array}{l} \vec{p}_1 = ( x_1 , y_1 , z_1 ) \\
\vec{p}_2 = ( x_2 , y_2 , z_2 ) \\
\vec{p}_3 = ( x_3 , y_3 , z_3 ) \end{array}$$
and their corresponding transformed vectors
$$\begin{array}{l} \vec{p}_4 = ( x_4 , y_4 , z_4 ) \\
\vec{p}_5 = ( x_5 , y_5 , z_5 ) \\
\vec{p}_6 = ( x_6 , y_6 , z_6 ) \end{array}$$
so that
$$\begin{cases}
\mathbf{M} \vec{p}_1 = \vec{p}_4 \\
\mathbf{M} \vec{p}_2 = \vec{p}_5 \\
\mathbf{M} \vec{p}_3 = \vec{p}_6 \end{cases}$$
Let $d$ be the triple product of the first three vectors,
$$d = \vec{p}_1 \cdot \left ( \vec{p}_2 \times \vec{p}_3 \right ) = 
x_1 ( y_2 z_3 - y_3 z_2 ) + x_2 ( y_3 z_1 - y_1 z_3 ) + x_3 ( y_1 z_2 - y_2 z_1 )$$
If $d \ne 0$, there exists a solution:
$$\begin{cases}
m_{11} = \left ( x_4 ( y_2 z_3 - z_2 y_3 ) + x_5 ( z_1 y_3 - y_1 z_3 ) + x_6 ( y_1 z_2 - z_1 y_2 ) \right ) / d \\
m_{12} = \left ( x_4 ( z_2 x_3 - x_2 z_3 ) + x_5 ( x_1 z_3 - z_1 x_3 ) + x_6 ( z_1 x_2 - x_1 z_2 ) \right ) / d \\
m_{13} = \left ( x_4 ( x_2 y_3 - y_2 x_3 ) + x_5 ( y_1 x_3 - x_1 y_3 ) + x_6 ( x_1 y_2 - y_1 x_2 ) \right ) / d \\
m_{21} = \left ( y_4 ( y_2 z_3 - z_2 y_3 ) + y_5 ( z_1 y_3 - y_1 z_3 ) + y_6 ( y_1 z_2 - z_1 y_2 ) \right ) / d \\
m_{22} = \left ( y_4 ( z_2 x_3 - x_2 z_3 ) + y_5 ( x_1 z_3 - z_1 x_3 ) + y_6 ( z_1 x_2 - x_1 z_2 ) \right ) / d \\
m_{23} = \left ( y_4 ( x_2 y_3 - y_2 x_3 ) + y_5 ( y_1 x_3 - x_1 y_3 ) + y_6 ( x_1 y_2 - y_1 x_2 ) \right ) / d \\
m_{31} = \left ( z_4 ( y_2 z_3 - z_2 y_3 ) + z_5 ( z_1 y_3 - y_1 z_3 ) + z_6 ( y_1 z_2 - z_1 y_2 ) \right ) / d \\
m_{32} = \left ( z_4 ( z_2 x_3 - x_2 z_3 ) + z_5 ( x_1 z_3 - z_1 x_3 ) + z_6 ( z_1 x_2 - x_1 z_2 ) \right ) / d \\
m_{33} = \left ( z_4 ( x_2 y_3 - y_2 x_3 ) + z_5 ( y_1 x_3 - x_1 y_3 ) + z_6 ( x_1 y_2 - y_1 x_2 ) \right ) / d
\end{cases}$$

If $\mathbf{M}$ is a pure rotation matrix, it will be orthogonal. If we use $\hat{r}_i = ( m_{i 1} ,\, m_{i 2} ,\, m_{i 3} )$ and $\hat{c}_j = ( m_{1 j} ,\, m_{2 j} ,\, m_{3 j} )$, and $\mathbf{M}$ is orthogonal, then
$$\begin{array}{l|l|l|l}
\hat{r}_1 \cdot \hat{r}_1 = 1 & \hat{c}_1 \cdot \hat{c}_1 = 1 &
\hat{r}_1 \times \hat{r}_1 = 0 & \hat{c}_1 \times \hat{c}_1 = 0 \\
\hat{r}_1 \cdot \hat{r}_2 = 0 & \hat{c}_1 \cdot \hat{c}_2 = 0 &
\hat{r}_1 \times \hat{r}_2 = \hat{r}_3 & \hat{c}_1 \times \hat{c}_2 = \hat{c}_3 \\
\hat{r}_1 \cdot \hat{r}_3 = 0 & \hat{c}_1 \cdot \hat{c}_3 = 0 &
\hat{r}_1 \times \hat{r}_3 = -\hat{r}_2 & \hat{c}_1 \times \hat{c}_3 = -\hat{c}_2 \\
\hline
\hat{r}_2 \cdot \hat{r}_1 = 0 & \hat{c}_2 \cdot \hat{c}_1 = 0 &
\hat{r}_2 \times \hat{r}_1 = -\hat{r}_3 & \hat{c}_2 \times \hat{c}_1 = -\hat{c}_3 \\
\hat{r}_2 \cdot \hat{r}_2 = 1 & \hat{c}_2 \cdot \hat{c}_2 = 1 &
\hat{r}_2 \times \hat{r}_2 = 0 & \hat{c}_2 \times \hat{c}_2 = 0 \\
\hat{r}_2 \cdot \hat{r}_3 = 0 & \hat{c}_2 \cdot \hat{c}_3 = 0 &
\hat{r}_2 \times \hat{r}_3 = \hat{r}_1 & \hat{c}_2 \times \hat{c}_3 = \hat{c}_1 \\
\hline
\hat{r}_3 \cdot \hat{r}_1 = 0 & \hat{c}_3 \cdot \hat{c}_1 = 0 &
\hat{r}_3 \times \hat{r}_1 = \hat{r}_2 & \hat{c}_3 \times \hat{c}_1 = \hat{c}_2 \\
\hat{r}_3 \cdot \hat{r}_2 = 0 & \hat{c}_3 \cdot \hat{c}_2 = 0 &
\hat{r}_3 \times \hat{r}_2 = -\hat{r}_1 & \hat{c}_3 \times \hat{c}_2 = -\hat{c}_1 \\
\hat{r}_3 \cdot \hat{r}_3 = 1 & \hat{c}_3 \cdot \hat{c}_3 = 1 &
\hat{r}_3 \times \hat{r}_3 = 0 & \hat{c}_3 \times \hat{c}_3 = 0 
\end{array}$$

When you are satisfied you have an orthogonal matrix, pick the [Euler or Tait-Bryan angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) you wish to use, you can [extract the angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms) by inspecting the matrix $\mathbf{M}$.

I personally do not use Euler angles or Tait-Bryan angles, because they are confusing (no single definition; you need to specify the rotation axes and their order, as Euler angles or Tait-Bryan angles refer to a *set* of definitions, not one definition) and problematic (gimbal lock in particular). I personally use [versors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor) and rotation matrices, and occasionally the [axis-angle representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-angle) and [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula).

---

One practical way to split a transformation back into a translation and rotation is to define the rotation as rotation around one of the vectors. This yields translation before a rotation, a rotation, and a translation after the rotation.

Let's assume we know three vectors before the transformation, $\vec{a}_1$, $\vec{a}_2$, and $\vec{a}_3$, and the three vectors after the transformation, $\vec{b}_1$, $\vec{b}_2$, $\vec{b}_3$, but not the transformation itself -- not the rotation $\mathbf{R}$ nor the translation after rotation $\vec{t}$:
$$\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{R}\vec{a}_1 + \vec{t} = \vec{b}_1 \\
\mathbf{R}\vec{a}_2 + \vec{t} = \vec{b}_2 \\
\mathbf{R}\vec{a}_3 + \vec{t} = \vec{b}_3 \end{array}$$
Since $\mathbf{R}$ describes a pure rotation, it is an orthogonal matrix.

We can split the above into pre- and post-translation thus:
$$\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{R}\left(\vec{a}_1 - \vec{t}_1 \right ) + \vec{t}_2 = \vec{b}_1 \\
\mathbf{R}\left(\vec{a}_2 - \vec{t}_1 \right ) + \vec{t}_2 = \vec{b}_2 \\
\mathbf{R}\left(\vec{a}_3 - \vec{t}_1 \right ) + \vec{t}_2 = \vec{b}_3 \end{array}$$
with $\vec{t} = \vec{t}_2 - \mathbf{R} \vec{t}_1$.

Now, if we pick $\vec{t}_1 = \vec{a}_i$ and $\vec{t}_2 = \vec{b}_i$, with $i$ being any of $1$, $2$, or $3$, and solve $\mathbf{R}$ using the other two vector pairs relative to $\vec{a}_i$ and $\vec{b}_i$, we will find **a** rotation that combined with the specified translation fulfills the requirements. Depending on the vectors and the rotation -- and in practice this is quite sensitive to rounding errors and such --, there may be multiple solutions. However, this should find a valid solution, unless the original vectors are parallel or degenerate.

For simplicity, let's pick $\vec{t}_1 = \vec{a}_1$ and $\vec{t}_2 = \vec{b}_1$. We now have a pure rotation $\mathbf{R}$, such that
$$\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{R}\left(\vec{a}_2 - \vec{a}_1\right) = \vec{b}_2 - \vec{b}_1 \\
\mathbf{R}\left(\vec{a}_3 - \vec{a}_1\right) = \vec{b}_3 - \vec{b}_1 \end{array}$$
The simplest way to construct $\mathbf{R}$ is to find the matrix $\mathbf{R}_1$ that rotates the coordinate system to match that used by the $a$ vectors, and $\mathbf{R}_2$ that rotates the coordinate system to match that used by the $b$ vectors. Then, we can express $\mathbf{R}$ as the inverse rotation to $\mathbf{R}_1$ followed by rotation $\mathbf{R}_2$.

Since rotation matrices are orthogonal, their inverse is their transpose, so
$$\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1^T$$

We can construct $\mathbf{R}_1$ and $\mathbf{R}_2$ by orthonormalizing the two vectors we have; the third basis vector is then the cross product of the first two.

Let $$\mathbf{R}_1 = \left [ \begin{matrix} \hat{e}_1 & \hat{e}_2 & \hat{e}_1\times\hat{e}_2 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
and $$\mathbf{R}_2 = \left [ \begin{matrix} \hat{e}_4 & \hat{e}_5 & \hat{e}_4\times\hat{e}_5 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
ie. $\hat{e}_i$ are the column vectors (basis unit vectors) in the rotation matrices.

We can use the first leftover vector to define the $x$ axis unit vector,
$$\hat{e}_1 = \frac{\vec{a}_2 - \vec{a}_1}{\lVert \vec{a}_2 - \vec{a}_1 \rVert} $$
$$\hat{e}_4 = \frac{\vec{b}_2 - \vec{b}_1}{\lVert \vec{b}_2 - \vec{b}_1 \rVert} $$
and orthonormalize the second vector against the first one,
$$\hat{e}_2 = \frac{\vec{a}_3 - \vec{a}_1 - \hat{e}_1 \left ( \hat{e}_1 \cdot (\vec{a}_3 - \vec{a}_1) \right )}{\lVert \vec{a}_3 - \vec{a}_1 - \hat{e}_1 \left ( \hat{e}_1 \cdot (\vec{a}_3 - \vec{a}_1) \right ) \rVert} $$
$$\hat{e}_5 = \frac{\vec{b}_3 - \vec{b}_1 - \hat{e}_4 \left ( \hat{e}_4 \cdot (\vec{b}_3 - \vec{b}_1) \right )}{\lVert \vec{b}_3 - \vec{b}_1 - \hat{e}_4 \left ( \hat{e}_4 \cdot (\vec{b}_3 - \vec{b}_1) \right ) \rVert} $$
As shown in the matrices above, the third basis unit vector is just the cross product of the two others,
$$\hat{e}_3 = \hat{e}_1 \times \hat{e}_2$$
$$\hat{e}_6 = \hat{e}_4 \times \hat{e}_5$$

In practice, you'd construct the unit vectors $\hat{e}_i$ first, copying them to the rotation matrices $\mathbf{R}_1$ and $\mathbf{R}_2$,
then compute the rotation via matrix multiplication, $\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1^T$, and finally calculate the translation after
rotation, $\vec{t} = \vec{b}_1 - \mathbf{R} \vec{a}_1$.

Comment: There’s also a translation involved: “The 3D object is **moved** and rotated...”

Comment: @amd: In that case, there are further limitations to the vectors, for a solution to exist. Actually, one could construct one set of basis unit vectors from $\vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1$, another set from $\vec{p}_5 - \vec{p}_4$ and $\vec{p}_6 - \vec{p}_4$, i.e. rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}_1$ that rotates the axes to parallel to the first two initial vectors, and rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}_2$ that rotates the axes to parallel to the first two final vectors. The rotation matrix is then $\mathbf{R}_2\mathbf{R}_1^{-1} = \mathbf{R}_2\mathbf{R}_1^T$.

Comment: Is there a strait forward answer how M will look like? Let's just focus on the rotation matrix.

Comment: @TinaJ: If the second set of vectors is the first one rotated only, then the $\mathbf{M}$ shown in my answer ($m_{11}, m_{12}, ... , m_{32}, m_{33}$) is the rotation matrix. Or did you want me to add the description on how to construct the alternative one, the one I mentioned in above comment starting with *"In that case, there are..."*?

Comment: That can help. But can you use my own variables A and B as origin and destination points?

Comment: @TinaJ: No, I don't see how that would work. You see, you specify three vectors with the same components `(xa, ya, za)`. That makes the three vectors one and the same. You really should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) notation, for readability. For example, if you use `$\vec{p}_1 = ( x_1 , y_1 , z_1 )$`, you get $\vec{p}_1 = ( x_1 , y_1 , z_1 )$. You need to fix the notation in your question to be **unambiquous**; we're not mind-readers here, and can only read what you write, not what you actually meant.

Answer (score 1):

For there to be a unique solution, the points on the object must not be colinear. Let’s proceed assuming that they are not.

Working in homogeneous coordinates, the transformation matrix will have the block form $$M=\begin{bmatrix}R&\mid&\mathbf t\end{bmatrix}$$ where $R$ is a $3\times3$ rotation matrix and $\mathbf t$ is a vector that represents the translation to be applied after rotation. The rotation matrix $R$ can itself be decomposed as $$R=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf u&\mathbf v&\mathbf u\times\mathbf v\end{bmatrix}$$ with $\|\mathbf u\|=\|\mathbf v\|=1$ and $\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf v=0$. Thus, you have nine unknowns in $M$: the coordinates of $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf t$. The correspondences of the “before” and “after” points can be summarized in the matrix equation $$\begin{bmatrix}R&\mid&\mathbf t\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A_1&A_2&A_3\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}B_1&B_2&B_3\end{bmatrix}.$$ This expands into a system of nine equations in the nine unknowns which, together with the constraints on $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$, can in principle be solved to give you $M$. In fact, there’s a lot of redundancy in $M$: the system is overdetermined since there are only six degrees of freedom (three for the rotation and three for the translation), but the three pairs of points provide nine constraints. In practice, you might need to do a least-squares fit or approximate $M$ some other way because of numerical errors.

However, as Nominal Animal describes in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2316667/265466), you don’t really need to solve this system of equations directly. $M$ can be found by breaking it down into a composition of simpler rigid motions, each of which is quite simple to compute. That computation doesn’t involve any inversions and only requires a couple of matrix multiplications, so even if you’re nbot working symbolically, in practice this is likely to give you a pretty good approximation to the true values of the axis and angle.

Once you have this matrix, you can then extract the rotation axis and angle or the Euler angles that correspond to the rotation using well-documented methods. See the Wikipedia articles on [rotation matrices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and [Euler angles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) for a starting place.

Comment: I can't speak for OP but your solution, while definitely promising-looking, isn't 100% clear to me. How did you prove this? Or do you have a source that gives a proof?

Comment: @Chris Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: If we're going item by item, I guess $(1)$ why we switched to a $4 \times 4$ matrix $M$, $(2)$ how you knew that matrix would have the prescribed block form, and $(3)$ how you wrote the form of $R$ in terms of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ (and what those vectors are).

Comment: @Chris (1) See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics and its linked articles. This allows the translation to be incorporated in the matrix. Since we’re not doing a perspective transform, a $3\times4$ matrix would’ve been suffficient. (2). Try building a rotation matrix and translation matrix and multiply them out. (3). The columns of $R$ are the images of the standard basis vectors, as is the case for *all* transformation matrices. A rotation matrix is orthogonal with determinant 1, so its columns form a right-handed orthonormal basis for the space.

Comment: Why do you use the notion of approximation here? I couldn't really get it, but are you sure this is the right answer? M should give a straight-forward absolute solution.

Comment: @TinaJ Mathematically, this does give you an exact solution. In practice, there’s floating-point roundoff and order-of-magnitude mismatches to contend with that can lead to deviations from the ideal solution and might even lead to an inconsistent system of equations. Values that should be zero will be very small numbers instead and instead of $1$s you’ll see values very close to $1$.