# Find principal axis of rotation

Tags: rotations

I have a body in 3D-space and I would like to calculate the rotation axis when the body moves from A to B. I know the location (x, y and z) and the orientation (rx, ry and rz (axis angles)) at both A and B.

I have read about Rodriguez' rotation formula and know how to find the axis of rotation, but how can I incorporate the translation components as well? 
Any help is appreciated!

/Daniel

Comment: You might not have enough information to find this transformation. There can be a rotation about the “orientation axis” itself that you’re not going to be able to account for with what you’ve said you’ve got to work with here. To put it another way, there’s an infinite number of rotations about different axes that will align the orientation vector at $A$ with that at $B$. Without further information, there’s nothing that tells you which one of these rotations to pick.

Comment: Ok, you may be right.

Comment: With the update that you made in [your answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2371049/265466), which uses three noncolinear points on the object and their images, this is now a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2316606/265466.

Comment: Any suggestions of how to proceed with my additional question below? any help is appreciated!!

Comment: It’s better to post follow-ups as separate questions, and it’s especially bad to post your new questions as updates to answers. Especially since this question’s been closed, it’s unlikely that anyone’s going to pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried a different way: using three points (p0, q0 and r0) on the rigid body.

I hope you can stand some matlab lingo.

%points before (x, y, z)

p0=[0.25    -0.34   -2.57]'+[1556 24.9 618.7]';

q0 = [-0.3995   -0.069  -1.487]'+[1600 -445 763]';

r0 = [-0.278    0.1376  -3.57]'+[1525 475 850.5]';

%points after

p1 = [-0.17 -0.47   -2.46]'+[1556 24.9 618.7]';

q1 = [0.99  -0.045  -1.42]'+[1600 -445 763]';

r1 = [0.52  0.11    -3.53]'+[1525 475 850.5]';

I then calculate the rotation vector as:

w = cross(((q1-q0)-(r1-r0)), ((p1-p0)-(r1-r0)))/dot(((q1-q0)-(r1-r0)), ((p1+p0)-(r1+r0)));

This seems to give reasonable results. Assuming this is correct I know the direction vector of the rotation, but how can I find the position of this vector?

### /Daniel

Thanks! However, the calculation of a point on the rotation vector is not clear to me. It was many years since I did this kind of computations, so please bear with me.
I found a short paper about this: http://robotics.caltech.edu/~jwb/courses/ME115/handouts/rodriguez.pdf

I have calculated the rotation vector as above, which corresponds to equation 8 in the paper. Now I also use equation 10 (in the paper) to calculate a point on the rotation vector.

p = 0.5*((cross(w, (p1-p0))/rot_angle) - (dot(w, p1 + p0).*w + p0 + p1));

where

rot_angle = norm(w) %this is tan(theta/2)

With the figures I have equation 10 yields:

p = [-1551.09 105.76 -555.65]

Is this a correct way to do it?

/Daniel

Comment: With three noncolinear points on the object, you can recover the entire transformation: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2316606/265466.